# Monthly percentage returns to actual values

Tags: r

I'm given three consequent monthly returns: 0.02, -0.03, 0.04. And I'm asked to plot the growth of an investment. Therefore I need to transform these into some kind of actual values. I think I can do it with `for` the following way:

```
test <- c(0.02, -0.03, 0.04)
z <- c(1)
for (i in 1:length(test)) {
    z[i+1] <- z[i] + z[i] * test[i]
}
z
```

But it's a bad practice to use `for`, I assume, and, on the other side, I bet it's also possible to achieve the same result with the `apply` family, isn't it?

Thus, I'd be grateful for any advice, thanks :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
z <- z*c(1, cumprod(1+test))
```

Example:

```
test <- c(0.02, -0.03, 0.04)
z <- 1
z <- z*c(1, cumprod(1+test))
```

The result of the multiplication is:

```
> z*c(1, cumprod(1+test))
[1] 1.000000 1.020000 0.989400 1.028976
```

Comment: Thanks, @jogo! And sorry for being so blind :).